# Retrieve row data based on indirect Max function value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

This spreadsheet tracks live song ratings for a popular band.  Users input their score in their own column and those scores are averaged into a community score (Column E).  Those song averages are averaged together to get a "show average" that is also in Column E but will never be close to the top 10 song averages so it should mess up this feature.

I am trying to have an automatic updating list that retrieves the top 10 rated songs (from column E) and lists them in descending order (highest rated at top). I can use the MAX value to get these ascending scores but am stuck in how I retrieve the other data (Columns A,B,C,D) that are the actual info corresponding to that song.

Here is a picture that should help:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(query(A:E,"select * order by E desc"),10,5)
```

`10` for the number of rows and `5` for all the columns.